# How to disable only dropdown not fieldlabel in EXTJS combobox

Tags: css, extjs, extjs6

How to disable only dropdown and the fieldLabel should be enabled and dropdown should be disabled(not able to select and should be grayed out)

Let me know how we can do it by CSS?

Answer (score 0):

This css will do the job. But its better to use a more specific selector.

```
.x-form-item-label {
    opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

Alternatively, you can create a DisplayField instead of using FieldLabel and place it near the dropdown.